# Does the value of std::list<T>::end() change after modifying list?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I'm trying to make use of the fact that iterators to lists remain valid after insertions and removals (except iterators to what you just removed). Is this also true of `std::list<T>::end();`

Suppose I try the following:

```
typedef std::list<int> list_int;

list_int myList;
list_int::iterator iter = myList.end();

myList.push_back(1);
myList.push_back(2);
myList.push_back(3);

if(iter == myList.end()) {
    /* do things here */
} else {
    /* do different things here */
    /* I don't expect this branch to ever execute */
}
```

This is important because elsewhere I might store a collection of iterators into this list, and I would test for validity by comparing against `myList.end()`. It's important that invalid iterators remain so even after insertions and removals.

Comment: I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6230350/596781) once...

Comment: Similar, yes. Your question does point that `myList.end()` has a unique value regardless of insertions and removals. My question asks whether this is standard behavior that I can depend on across systems and compilers.

Comment: *"iterators to lists remain valid after insertions and removals"* - and `std::list::end` returns an iterator to the list. So what?

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647007/does-stdlistclear-invalidate-stdlistend-iterator). Its answers and comments cite relevant parts of the standard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value of `std::list`s end iterator never changes during the lifetime of the list. It is always valid, always the same and always corresponds to the imaginary "past the end" element of the list. This means that the value of `some_list.end()` memorized at any point in the list's lifetime will always be the same as the value of `some_list.end()` at any other point of its lifetime.

The language specification doesn't state it explicitly. However, there's simply no valid operation on the list that would invalidate the end iterator or associate its value with some other location.

In your example the second branch of that `if` will never execute.

If I'm not missing anything, the same is true for `std::map` and `std::set` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple test by placing a `cout` in each clause of the IF statement? By doing so, you will realize that the **first** clause (`iter == myList.end()`) is indeed **true**.

I am going to base my reasoning simply on this documentation of the end() function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/end/. It says: "Returns an iterator referring to the *past-the-end* element in the list container." Hence, if the iterator pointing to *past-the-end* is returned, then shouldn't it always be pointing *past-the-end*? Elements inserted before this *past-the-end* point shouldn't affect where the iterator is pointing to (which is a spot after the last element of the list).