# Does std::list::clear invalidate std::list::end iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl, stdlist

Check this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    mylist.push_back(1);
    std::list<int>::iterator i = mylist.end();
    if( i == mylist.end() )
        printf( "end is end\n" );

    mylist.clear();
    if( i == mylist.end() )
        printf( "never get here because Microsoft seems to "
                "think the iterator is no longer safe.\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Now, according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/clear/) this shouldn't be a problem, and in release mode, I think this is fine and doesn't cause any issues really, but debugging becomes impossible as this just bails without letting me continue. Any pointers?

Comment: Interesting. I thought `.end` is also invalidated, but the article says the opposite. It's interesting, that http://ideone.com/Y338N8 executes it as expected. +1

Comment: That makes perfect sense as the code I'm trying to port to Windows was written targeting MacOS and Linux. Both are running GCC, as ideone does. I guess this is a library bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other answers point out that, in general, you can't rely on a container's past-the-end iterator remaining valid when the container is cleared. However, the past-the-end iterator of a list should indeed remain valid:

> C++11 23.3.5.4/3 *Effects:* Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements.

The past-the-end iterator does not refer to any element, so should not be invalidated.

Comment: +1, removed my answer. While I recall from previous conversations that using a dynamically allocated sentry is explicitly supported by the standard, this does not mean that `clear()` needs to release it. Just double checked our implementation and `clear()` is implemented as `erase(begin(),end())` and doesn't invalidate the `end()` iterators. This should be reported to Microsoft as a bug in their implementation.

Comment: Thanks, Mike and @DavidRodríguez-dribeas.  Yes, this is a bug in the Visual C++ 2012 `std::list` implementation.  It is a regression from Visual C++ 2010.  Note that `erase` is similarly broken.  I checked in a fix for this bug a few months ago, and the fix will appear in the next released version of the Visual C++ Standard Library.  The fix fixes both `erase` and `clear`.  (This bug was reported by a customer, but not via Microsoft Connect, so I don't have a link to which I can refer you.)

Comment: Reported to Microsoft, fixed but only in VS2013: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808659/std-list-t-erase-in-debug-mode-invalidates-end-iterator

Comment: Funnier is reasoning about reverse iterators. In that case `rend()` I suppose is invalidated when the first element is deleted...

Answer (score 4):

From C++11, Table 100 (Sequence container requirements):

> `clear()` [...]  may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.

And `std::list` is of course a sequence container template (23.3.5.1/2):

> A list satisfies all of the requirements of a container, of a reversible container (given in two tables in 23.2), **of a sequence container**, including most of the optional sequence container requirements (23.2.3), and of an allocator-aware container (Table 99). The exceptions are the operator[] and at member functions, which are not provided. Descriptions are provided here only for operations on list that are not described in one of these tables **or for operations where there is additional semantic information**.

Comment: To add to this: the `end` iterator is a singular value and most node base containers that guarantee stability of iterators only give this guarantee for non-singular values.

Comment: I believe that should be read as "there are containers for which it does invalidate past-the-end iterators and containers for which it does not". Otherwise, it would be a conflicting specification

Comment: But the list-specific specification, 23.3.5.4/3, says "Invalidates **only** the iterators and references to the erased elements."

Comment: @MikeSeymour is correct. The general requirements in table 100 apply only when the particular container requirements don't state otherwise. In this particular case, the requirements for `std::list<>::clear()` explicitly make stricter guarantees.

Answer (score -2):

This is in fact invalid.
Iterators are only valid on the current state container.
Once you add or remove items, the iterator is no longer valid.

The article you link does not say what you are doing is valid. They get a new iterator after the clear.

The reason it doesn't show up in release code is because the debugging that picks up the issue is disabled.

Comment: And one more time: According to the link in the question: "All iterators, references and pointers related to this container are invalidated, except the end iterators."

Comment: @meh: Nope, you are wrong, the end iterator *can* be invalidated

Comment: "Once you add or remove items, the iterator is no longer valid." That's not true in general; each container has its own invalidation rules, and `list` iterators remain valid as long as the element they refer to is still in a list.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - I'm not saying anything, I just copied a quote from the article, linked in the question :) Also, +1 for Mike's opinion